# Why is the value of 0xAA the same after executing this code?

Tags: c++

Question is :
Assuming flags = 0xAA, what is the value of flags after the following statement is executed?

its a multiple choice qn with options being 0xA8, 0x54, 0xAA and AA2.
why is it not 0xA8 though?

cout << (flags << 2);

Comment: Why would the value of `flags` change? You don't assign anything to it.

Comment: `flags << 2` is the same as `flags * 2`. Both statements don't change the variable.

Comment: You are confusing `<<` with `<<=`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik It's `flags * 4`, but yeah. `flags << 1` would be `flags * 2`.

Comment: `operator<<` for `std::cout` does indeed modify the `cout` object. That may be the source of confusion. But outside of `<iostream>`, `<<` is just a left shift operation for integral values, equivalent to a multiplication with a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming flags = 0xAA, what is the value of flags after the following statement is executed?
>
> ```
> cout << (flags << 2)
> ```

It will be 0xAA.

> why is it not 0xA8 though

Because bit shift operator doesn't modify either operand and because stream insertion operator doesn't modify the right hand operand.

Furthermore, even the result of `0xAA << 2` is not 0xA8. It is 0x2A8.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention: `0xaa << 2 == 0x2a8` will always be true due to integral promotion, `flags <<= 2` indeed might indeed result in `0xa8`, though, if `flags` is of type `uint8_t`...